Cannot get django-admin css file in "Django + nginx + docker"
I could not serve the Django-admin's static files...
I think.. It can't not recognize the reverse-proxy path. the location /static/admin/
Literally, The Django static folder is in upstream django server.
There is nginx.conf and the inside docker container with django.
Please tell me the solution...
nginx
# nginx
upstream react {
    server 10.180.225.1:3000;
}

upstream django {
    server 10.180.226.1:8000;
    keepalive 100;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    include mime.types;
    
    location /static/admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://django;         
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;        
        add_header Test "This is for proxy pass.";
    }
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;     
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://react;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

docker exec -it back-web /bin/bash ls...

Django Admin page

